# Space movement or Propulsion

Tags: propulsion

When a spacecraft is moving through outerspace does the movement of the craft create a headwind and if so could that headwind charge or create electricity by an engine that is moved by the headwind i.e. a converted aircraft engine with  with a large alternator or several alternators that help charge the spacecraft

Comment: Basically spacecrafts move through empty space (especially true for outer one). What headwind are you talking about? Do you mean Bussard's ramjet?

Comment: Like the wind moves a fan. Just thinking that the movement could move the  turbine that turns  alternator that could power the device.  These modified turbines could be 6 inches in diameter and maybe 5 feet long and have several alternators in line.

Answer (score 2):

On Earth, a headwind occurs because there is air and a relative velocity between the moving object and the surrounding air. [Outer space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_space) is essentially empty, unless you count the odd hydrogen atom per cubic meter. It's hardly going to create a headwind at any conceivable speed.

Even if there was a headwind, and the means to use it to generate power, what is going on is that energy of motion of the vehicle is being taken from that motion and converted to something else (whatever you needed it for). That will cause the vehicle to slow down or require an extra push to maintain speed. You don't get [something for nothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetual_motion).

It is usually simpler, easier, and more efficient to generate power by other means than by taking it from the motion of the vehicle, no matter what sort of vehicle we are talking about, or what medium it is traveling through.

Comment: The electric boosters that they were talking about we're going to be moving the vehicle anyway what would it matter if it had a little resistance that charges the spacecraft

Comment: Consider the analogy of an electric car equipped with a windmill to recharge the battery. Just another case of a perpetual motion machine, attempting to get more energy out of a system than is either stored or added. FWIW electric boosters only create tiny amounts of thrust; even a tiny amount of drag would be significant.

Comment: Note: Bicycles used to power their lights by running a small generator from the nearby wheel. Cars and airplanes still do power their auxiliary systems with alternators attached to the driveshaft(s), and some airplanes use dedicated ram-air turbines to tap into airspeed energy directly. No doubt there are other examples of similar setups. So it would be more accurate to say that taking power from the motion of the vehicle is only suitable for powering secondary systems.